# image resize in jquery

Tags: jquery

i have an application when image zoomin/zoomout on "focus" and "blur" events respectively. i have used this function for that

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {


  var timer;
  var w="img.width";
  var h="img.height";
      $('button:has(img)').focus(function () {
         var $image = $(this).find('img');

         timer = setTimeout(function() {

                $image.animate({
                    'width': "+=15px",
                    'height': "+=15px"
                }, 500);  
              }, 
              1000);

      });

      $('button:has(img)').blur(function () {

        if (timer !== null) clearTimeout(timer);
        $(this).find('img').animate({
                'width': "-=15px",
                'height': "-=15px"
            }, 0);
      });

</script>
```

now my question is there any other way in which i can read image size and add 15px to image width and height and pass those value instead of doing this:

`'width': "+=15px" and height': "+=15px pass this values to focus() and 'width': "-=15px" and height': "-=15px to blur().

i tried doing following changes but didnt work

var w= "image.width";
var h = "image.height";
var updated_w = w+10;
var updated_h= h+10;

passing w,h to blur() and updated_w, updated_h to focus(). this will not work.

Comment: i guess the blur part does not work? or what's the problem??

Comment: You can always ask `$('img').height();` Or isn't that what you are referring to?

Comment: @marnix i do get image height and width using function wat you said now my question is how will i add some value say x to it and write back that value to image.width/image.height to update its value. code sinpate will be helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I understand from comments. Your call is made too often and you need some original to keep. First initialize the images then:

```
$(document.ready(function()
{
    $('button img').each(function()
    {
        // save the data inside the element with jQuery
        $.data(this, 'orgH', $(this).height());
        $.data(this, 'orgW', $(this).width());
    });

    // i omitted the timeout, but do as you wish
    // just an example of $.data
    $('button:has(img)').focus(function()
    {
        $('img',this).each(function()
        {
            $(this).animate({
            width: $.data(this,'orgW') + 15 + 'px' // where THIS is the image element again
            });
        });
    });
});
```

*HINTS*

The setTimeout event has `this` as window again. So we need to do something with the focus, because the above code is working fine without timeouts.

**NEW UPDATE**

I put the same functionality to the blur.
Your code is working fine when you do this, but you **really** have to check your keyInput code, because it is a bit buggy. firebug even gives errors, because you don't have a case for TAB yet.

```
var timerFocus;
var timerBlur;
$('button:has(img)').focus(function()
{
    if(timerBlur !== null) clearTimeout(timerBlur);
    timerFocus = setTimeout(function(el)
    {
        $('img',el).each(function()
        {
            $(this).animate({
            width: $.data(this,'orgW') + 15 + 'px', // where THIS is the image element again
            height : $.data(this,'orgH') + 15 + 'px'
            });
        });
    },500,this); // THIS is the button element
});

$('button:has(img)').blur(function ()
{
    if (timerFocus !== null) clearTimeout(timerFocus);
    timerBlur = setTimeout(function(el)
    {
        $('img',el).each(function()
        {
            $(this).animate({
                width: $.data(this,'orgW')-15+'px', // WATCH THIS COMMA!
                height: $.data(this,'orgH')-15+'px'
            });
        });
    },500,this);
});
```

Comment: hope you help me out solving this issue.

Comment: @marnix could you please suggest me something. i am stuck

Comment: @rashmi: easy i'm working on it. What I can already tell you, is that you loose your `THIS` focus, because of your setTimeout function. The `THIS` is the window again probably. Without the timeout it works fine.

Comment: @ marnix, sorry to disturb you. is there any alternative for this. i cant remove timer form my application as it is important part of my application. :(

Comment: @rashmi, timer is just fine to use, but you have to give your element as a parameter. jsFiddle is hating me right now, so I stop it, but what you want is very good possible. See edited answer for some extra hints.

Comment: ok marnix i will try out with hint you have given me. if possible can you try adding demo in jsfiddle when you free. i wanted it as soon as possible. again sorry to disturb you. and thanks alot for your help

Comment: you have just mentioned for width. adding height similar way behaves unexpectedly. what about blur function. :(. sorry to disturb you so much. it would be very help full if you upload demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: @rashmi: Does width work now? Can you send the JSFiddle so we can work from there? Put it in your question, so other people can see what you're doing as well.

Comment: @marnix, i have given jsfiddle have look. ya width works fine to an extent. if u see demo u will get idea.

Comment: @marnix, hey zoomin is working fine. how do i do zoomout similarly could you please help

Comment: @rashmi: Ok I updated my code again. Please look at it closely and redesign your keyInput methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, but you will loose the zooming effect.

```
$('button:has(img)').blur(function () {

        if (timer !== null) clearTimeout(timer);
        var image = $(this).find('img');
        var new_width = image.width() - 15;
        var new_height = image.height() - 15;
        image.css('width', new_width+"px");
        image.css('height', new_height+"px");
});
```

Comment: i want both zoomin/zoomout to work as this is very much required to my application

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error, I try it and work fine for me:

you miss below:

`});`

final code is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var timer;
        var w="img.width";
        var h="img.height";
        $('button:has(img)').focus(function () {
            var $image = $(this).find('img');

            timer = setTimeout(function() {

                $image.animate({
                    'width': "+=15px",
                    'height': "+=15px"
                }, 500);
            },
            1000);

        });

        $('button:has(img)').blur(function () {

            if (timer !== null) clearTimeout(timer);
            $(this).find('img').animate({
                'width': "-=15px",
                'height': "-=15px"
            }, 0);
        });
    });
</script>
```